# SQL Server : deny select on recreated table

Tags: sql-server, sql-grant

In SQL Server 2017, I have a user with ddladmin privileges that drops and recreates a table regularly. We need to have deny select on that table.

Only when the table is dropped, it loses the deny. I do not want to grant the user securityadmin.

How can I make sure the deny select on this table is retained each time it is recreated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...adjust

```
revert
go

-- drop trigger deny_select_on_frequentlydroppedtable on database
create or alter trigger deny_select_on_frequentlydroppedtable 
on database  
with execute as 'dbo' 
for CREATE_TABLE
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    
    --when table name = frequentlydroppedtable
    if EVENTDATA().value('(EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname') = 'frequentlydroppedtable' 
    begin
        declare @tbl nvarchar(500) = concat(quotename(EVENTDATA().value('(EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'sysname')), '.', quotename(EVENTDATA().value('(EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname')));
        declare @user nvarchar(150) = EVENTDATA().value('(EVENT_INSTANCE/UserName)[1]', 'sysname');
        
        if @user <> 'dbo' and IS_ROLEMEMBER('db_owner', @user) = 0 and IS_ROLEMEMBER('db_ddladmin', @user) = 1 --... any ddl admin gets deny when they create the table :)
        begin
            declare @sql nvarchar(500) = 'deny select on ' + @tbl + ' to ' + quotename(@user);
            exec(@sql)
        end
    end
end
go

--dbo or ....
drop table if exists frequentlydroppedtable;
go
create table frequentlydroppedtable(id int);
go
--works
select * from frequentlydroppedtable
go


--create a test db_ddladmin
create user test_db_ddladmin without login;
go
alter role db_ddladmin add member test_db_ddladmin;
go
execute as user = 'test_db_ddladmin'
go
drop table if exists frequentlydroppedtable;
go
create table frequentlydroppedtable(id int);
go
--permission violation, deny select
select * from frequentlydroppedtable
go

revert
go

--cleanup
drop table if exists frequentlydroppedtable;
go
drop user test_db_ddladmin;
go
drop trigger deny_select_on_frequentlydroppedtable on database
go
```

Comment: My issues were all user related. This turned out to be exactly what I needed. Thank you!